# How to calculate total developed length with a dedicated recirculation line “recirc line”

Tags: plumbing

How do you calculate the total developed length, necessary for determining proper pipe sizing, when using a dedicated recirc line?

You generally calculate using your furthest fixture. If you have a recirc line does your furthest fixture become the water heater where the recirc line ends?

For eg; if it’s 10’ from meter to water heater, and then 10’ from water heater to furthest fixture my Total Developed Length is 20’. If I have a recirc line straight back to the water heater does it make my Total Developed Length 30’?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no change. You're not supplying water to the water heater. You're supplying water to the fixture.

Recirculation is a relatively low flow in circles, and not part of supply at all.